# Error, (in Matrix) this entry is too tall or too short: 1 when attempting to define Matrix in Maple

Tags: matrix, vector, linear-algebra, dimensions, maple

I get the following error message when attempting to create the 3x3 Matrix T in Maple
 where:

```
T:= Matrix([[0,1,0],[a,1,0],[b,1,9]])
```

and the error message

```
Error, (in Matrix) this entry is too tall or too short: 1
```

Note that the `with(LinearAlgebra)` package is activated. I do not understand why the central coordinate of the matrix is the only one to get error message, any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The code snippet, as you've shown it, runs fine. Here it is, producing the expected output.

```
restart;
with(LinearAlgebra):
T:= Matrix([[0,1,0],[a,1,0],[b,1,9]]);

                    [0    1    0]
                    [           ]
               T := [a    1    0]
                    [           ]
                    [b    1    9]
```

What's probably gone wrong is that either the name **a** or **b** has previously been assigned a value (possibly a Vector, or Matrix) and that you call thus denotes an attempt to flatten that. But then there'd be a mismatch with the scalars 1 and 0 in the same row or column.

For example,

```
restart;
with(LinearAlgebra):

a := Vector([1,2]):

Matrix([[0,1,0],[a,1,0],[b,1,9]]);
  Error, (in Matrix) this entry is too tall or too short: 1
```

So, are either **a** or **b** assigned with non-scalar values? If so, then try unassigning them first, or reconsider what you're trying to accomplish.